# Format LocalDateTime using FormatStyle.MEDIUM plus time zone

Tags: java, date

I have a LocalDateTime object that I format as follows:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
System.out.println(localDateTime.format(formatter));
```

That prints a nicely readable date of `Oct 20, 2021 1:00:02 PM`.

But I would like to also add the time zone. My understanding is I need to use ZonedDateTime:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(zdt);
```

But that produces the not so readable `2021-10-20T13:00:02.921-04:00[America/New_York]`.

Is there some way to format a ZonedDateTime so it's concise and readable like that produced by *FormatStyle.MEDIUM*, but also appended by the timezone (e.g: `Oct 20, 2021 1:00:02 PM EST`)?

Note: I gather from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981914/3368818) that I should *not* actually use "pseudo-zones", such as **EST**, due to their non-standardized nature.

Comment: Must you use `MEDIUM`? Using `LONG` or `FULL` typically gives you a timezone.

Comment: It's a great question. Using `LONG` is apparently about the same, but with the month spelled out in full. It's probably my best, and simplest, way to go. I guess I'm just being particular in that I would rather keep the month abbreviated while also adding the time zone - if there's a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks all for such great answers! Most every one works perfectly for my use case.

Comment: Printing `EST`, that depends a lot. Australian readers will understand Australian Eastern Standard Time, North American readers the North American ditto, God knows what readers elsewhere will assume. Think twice, but if presented in a context where the ambiguity somehow isn't an issue, `EST` is fine (only never try to parse it back).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

If you want a hint as to the time zone in use, use the `LONG` format for time-of-day portion. Optionally specify a different format such as `MEDIUM` for the date portion.

```java
ZonedDateTime
    .now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
    .format(
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime( 
                FormatStyle.MEDIUM ,     // Date portion style.
                FormatStyle.LONG         // Time-of-day portion style.
            )   
            .withLocale( Locale.US )     // Locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in localizing.
    )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/lLuNq5).

> Oct 20, 2021, 4:48:46 PM EDT

Never use `EDT`, `CST`, `IST`, and such for data-exchange. Do not attempt parsing of such values. These are not [real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), are not standardized, and are not even unique!

## Avoid `LocalDateTime.now`

I cannot imagine any scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. You capture the date and time-of-day but lack the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So a `LocalDateTime` by definition **cannot represent a moment**, is *not* a point on the timeline.

If you want to capture the current moment without committing to a particular time zone, capture the current moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment as seen in UTC.
```

## Use `ZonedDateTime.now`

If you want to capture the current moment as seen in `America/New_York` time zone, start with a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
```

To generate text representing a *java.time* object, use `toString` method to get text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. While such output may seem less readable at first glance, the standard formats are designed to be maximally readable by people across cultures.

To get a localized format, I suggest you let *java.time* automatically localize.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
System.out.println( "zdt represented in standard ISO 8601 format: " + zdt.toString() );

Locale locale = Locale.US ; 
DateTimeFormatter f_US = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String outputLocalized_US = zdt.format( f_US ) ;
String outputLocalized_CA_fr = zdt.format( f_US.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ) ;

System.out.println( outputLocalized_US ) ;
System.out.println( outputLocalized_CA_fr ) ;
```

When run.

```
zdt represented in standard ISO 8601 format: 2021-10-20T16:37:57.752554-04:00[America/New_York]
Oct 20, 2021, 4:37:57 PM
20 oct. 2021 16 h 37 min 57 s
```

## Separate formats for date & time

You can specify different formats for the date versus time-of-day portions. Use a longer format for time-of-day portion to get a hint of the time zone while using a shorter format for date portion, if you so desire.

```java
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime( 
                FormatStyle.MEDIUM ,     // Date portion format.
                FormatStyle.LONG         // Time-of-day portion format.
            )
```

Comment: This is great info. Just to clarify, by "Time-of-day portion" do you mean "time zone"?

Comment: @JWoodchuck There is no separate time zone part when generating text. Formatting of the time zone indicator is controlled by the time-of-day formatting.

Comment: It's clear to me now why java.time api is superior to the older approaches (e.g., java.util.Date, java.sql.Date). But am I correct in understanding that those others are not yet "officially" deprecated? I still come across people using those older objects while the better approach is available.

Comment: @JWoodchuck They were at one point marked for official deprecation, but that was inexplicably canceled. Notice that the new conversion methods between modern and legacy were added to the *old* classes, making room to deprecate or even remove them. They really should be deprecated as the *java.time* classes entirely replace their functionality. That is not the only old part of Java that should be deprecated. Take for example the `char` type that is physically incapable of representing most characters. Old code and old tutorials prolong the life of of such technologies past their natural end.

Comment: Thanks much, @Basil Bourque! To follow up, is there any easy way to change the resulting time to 24 hour time?

Comment: @JWoodchuck When using `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods, localization details including 12-hour vs 24-hour are determined according to the locale-specific rules. [As of Java 9+](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252), the default source for locale rules is the [CLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) published by the Unicode Consortium. If you want something different than those rules, first reconsider if you have specified the appropriate locale. Perhaps specifying a sub-culture is in order. Otherwise, specify a custom formatting pattern of your own design.

Comment: Thanks, @Basil Bourque. It seems to me a real gap that there would be no easy way to format 24 hr (“military”) time in the java.time api regardless of locale. All examples I’ve found thus far use SimpleDateFormat. That’s considered a legacy object, correct? They also seem to involve the hacky approach of artificially adding 8 hours to the actual time.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some way to format a ZonedDateTime so it reads similar to
> that produced by `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`, but is appended by the
> timezone - say, something like: `Oct 20, 2021 4:05:13 PM EST`?

You can use the format, `MMM d, uuuu h:mm:ss a zzz` with the `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, uuuu h:mm:ss a zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(now.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Oct 20, 2021 6:41:45 PM EDT
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2ipF1h)

Answer (score 2):

the ZonedDateTime can retrieve the current ZoneId. With the Zone, you can just use the `getDisplayName(TextStyle style, Locale locale)` getter. Just experiment which TextStyle is the best for you.

```
zdt.getZone().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)
==> ET
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you use `LONG` or `FULL` for the time style, the zone will be included:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.LONG);
System.out.println(zdt.format(formatter));
```

In the US locale, this prints:

```
Oct 20, 2021, 4:34:16 PM EDT
```

This is [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)):

> The `FULL` and `LONG` styles typically require a time-zone. When formatting using these styles, a ZoneId must be available, either by using `ZonedDateTime` or `withZone(java.time.ZoneId)`.

In this case, a time style of `LONG` happens to be the same as `MEDIUM`, but if you have to use `MEDIUM` for some reason, you can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and add the zone by hand:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM))
        .appendLiteral(" ")
        .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT).toFormatter();
System.out.println(zdt.format(formatter));
```

The advantage of this is that you can choose what style of timezone name you want. On the other hand, you might run into localisation issues, because I'm not sure if it is natural in all locales to put the timezone last.